# Comparing the WAMMI and SUS scales

Tags: usability-testing, sus

From doing a lot of research about standardized measurement for usability, I came across the WAMMI questionnaire which looks at a few of the factors in usability that goes into more detail than the SUS scale.

**Just wondering if there are any experiences or comparisons made between the two types of measures.**

Given that there hasn't be more discussion about the WAMMI questionnaire, I am wondering if people think if it offers a lot more for benchmarking user experience/usability?

You can find a [description](http://www.wammi.com/whatis.html) of the scale along with the actual [questions](http://www.wammi.com/using.html) (a link is provided on the page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me it's a swings and roundabouts discussion. Each has some advantages and disadvantages.

Here are some pointers to some research / background that should help you decide between them:

- [A comparison of current approaches to usability measurement](http://www.ucc.ie/en/apsych/staff/rm/K_and_M_2009.pdf).
- [SUS: A Retrospective](http://www.upassoc.org/upa_publications/jus/2013february/brooke2.html)
- [A Comparison of Questionnaires for Assessing Website Usability](http://www.upassoc.org/usability_resources/conference/2004/UPA-2004-TullisStetson.pdf)

(and if you go for SUS I would recommend using the postively worded varient since it reduces confusion and errors - see [Are Both Positive And Negative Items Necessary In Questionnaires?](http://www.measuringusability.com/positive-negative.php)).